# SQLAlchemy Columns result processing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2, field

I'm working with a IBM DB2 database using ibm_db2 driver and sqlalchemy.
My model is:

```
class User(Model):
    id          = Column('UID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    user        = Column('USER', String(20))
    password    = Column('PASSWORD', String(10))
    name        = Column('NAME', String(30))
```

String fields from the database (e.g. **name**) comes in the form of:

```
>>> "John                                "
```

, where the value is filled right with blanks to the full length of the field by schema.

I need to change this behavior to the sqlalchemy type String (or a derivative thereof) produced follow (e.g. **value.strip()**) before output results by **query.all()**:

```
>>> "John"
```

How can I do this?

**@property** decorator is not applicable. I need to change the behavior of a standard sqlalchemy String class.

Comment: Did you create this table by SQLAlchemy or by hand? Seems that you have a CHAR column instead of VARCHAR?

Comment: I was wondering, why you needed to do that ? what's wrong with the current behavior ? for what this behavior is disturbing/resulting ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not want to change the behaviour of the standard String but to make a new type (you can then rename it to String per module basis or whatever) but it is cleanest that way:

```
from sqlalchemy import types

class StrippedString(types.TypeDecorator):
    """
    Returns CHAR values with spaces stripped
    """

    impl = types.String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        "No-op"
        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        """
        Strip the trailing spaces on resulting values.
        If value is false, we return it as-is; it might be none
        for nullable columns
        """
        return value.rstrip() if value else value

    def copy(self):
        "Make a copy of this type"
        return StrippedString(self.impl.length)
```

Now you can use `StrippedString` instead of `String`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need to implement nop functions: The default will handle them.

Comment: True, copied from sa docs and thought I keep it for completeness

Comment: This will break with nullable char columns ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'). I went with `return value.rstrip() if value else value`, because maximizing value is a good thing.

Comment: Maybe casting column to str and using strip() method will work