# Stripping whitespace generically for all String fields - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, string-parsing

I am using SQLAlchemy through Flask-SQLAlchemy as the ORM for a web app.

I'd like to automatically leading and trailing strip whitespace (e.g. `str.strip`) when assigning to any string field.

One way to do this would be the following, but it would need to be specified for each and every string field:

```
class User(db.Model):
    _email = db.Column('email', db.String(100), primary_key=True)
    @hybrid_property
    def email(self): return self._email
    @email.setter
    def email(self, data): self._email = data.strip()
```

I would like to do this more generically for every String field (without having to write the above for each).

Comment: Related, but a "mirror" of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413748/sqlalchemy-columns-result-processing

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to create a custom [augmented string type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types) that handles such processing:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator

class StrippedString(TypeDecorator):

    impl = db.String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        # In case you have nullable string fields and pass None
        return value.strip() if value else value

    def copy(self, **kw):
        return StrippedString(self.impl.length)
```

You'd then use this in place of plain `String` in your models:

```
class User(db.Model):
    email = db.Column(StrippedString(100), primary_key=True)
```

This does not work exactly the same as your own implementation in that the processing takes place when the value is to be bound to a query as a parameter, or in other words a bit later:

```
In [12]: u = User(email='     so.much@white.space     ')

In [13]: u.email
Out[13]: '     so.much@white.space     '

In [14]: session.add(u)

In [15]: session.commit()

In [16]: u.email
Out[16]: 'so.much@white.space'
```